# Refresh token in python script does not seem to work for Google Drive

Tags: python, refresh, google-oauth

I am using this Python script below to upload files to a Google drive. It uploads fine the first time when user interaction is required to get the authorization key. However, when I try to upload the file again the error appears:

raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&alt=json returned "Invalid Upload Request">

What does this exactly mean?
I am guessing the refresh token isn't exactly doing what I want it to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage

CLIENT_ID = '*************************************************************************'
CLIENT_SECRET = '*****************************'

OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

FILENAME = '/home/student/Desktop/TraceRoute.kml'

CRED_FILENAME = 'credentials'

### For storing token
storage = Storage(CRED_FILENAME)

if not storage.get():
    # Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve authorization code
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

    ### Storing access token and a refresh token in CRED_FILENAME
    storage.put(credentials)
else:
    ### Getting access_token,expires_in,token_type,Refresh_toke info from CRED_FILENAME                    to 'credentials'
credentials = storage.get()

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

# Insert a file
media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
body = {
    'title': 'My document',
    'description': 'A test document',
    'mimeType': 'text/plain'
}

file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
pprint.pprint(file)
```

Comment: As I use Python3 and the google-api-client only support Python2, I've used this little library that, after a couple of changes, works fine for my. https://gist.github.com/SalvaJ/9638710

Comment: paste the failing http request and response into your question